# Detect HTML5 Context Menu Support with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't notice it in Modernizr's documentation but I imagine you create a `menu` element then check if it exists?  My only concern is that the browser may support that but not **type** `context`.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a rather shoddy solution that returns `true` for Firefox as far as I can tell then returns `false` for Chrome, IE and Opera. Check it out:

```js
// Detect context menu support.

function contextMenuSupported() {

    var oMenu = document.createElement("menu");

    // Kind of backwards but seems to work.

    if (oMenu.type == "list")
        return true;

    return false;

}
```

Let me know if that just **horrifies** you.  It *seems* when a menu element is created with a browser that supports it, certain attributes are intrinsically defined.

Comment: Opera currently says "undefined" for type.

Comment: Does Opera support context menus?  Please let me know and I'll adapt it -- very simple fix.

Comment: No, it does not - no fix needed. Just wanted to say that you can add Opera to the list of "false" results...